# Common Header and footer error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just learnt about common header and footer technique .. Below is the code i have written 
I can't figure out what is wrong with this code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <script>
        $("#header").load("header.html");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your `js` file and `header.html` in the same directory as the above page?

Comment: What did u get from this code?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz Yes it is in the same directory

Comment: IMO it would be better to place includes in server-side code, then there is no 'popup' when the new content is added to the DOM, and it saves on additional server requests.

Comment: @TepkenVannkorn i am trying to get a common header for all my html files

Comment: I meant what have u seen from this code. Any javascript errors in console?

Comment: @TepkenVannkorn NO it does not show any error .. it just doesn't load my Heade.html file

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan's suggestion, you should load parts of your html using Server side such as PHP or ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with other jQuery library version and it was running to me.

I had use the `jquery@1.10.1` library, and the `header.html` in the same directory.

[You could see this running here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZToEjnfb2pbdKHEzRw7)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using jquery. this is an alternative way that i use and works fine.

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });
})
```

now use data-load on any element to call its contents from external html file
you just have to add line to your html code where you want the content to be placed.

example

```
<nav data-load="sidepanel.html"></nav>
<nav data-load="footer.html"></nav>
```